# JQuery: Close toggled boxes when a different area is clicked on image map?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a map of London Underground that opens a box of information to the right of the map when a station is clicked on. Is there a way to get each box to close and open a new one when a different station is clicked, rather than having to click that station again to close the panel?

Kings Cross and Baker Street used in this example.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/nj3h65Ld/1/

Comment: I can click on a few things but i don't get a info box at all

Comment: Your fiddle doesnt seem to work.

Comment: `$(".boxes).hide()` will hide all div's with class `boxes`

Answer (score 1):

In your fiddle, you need to add the ID "BS" to the corresponding area, otherwise only Kings Cross will work.

If you replace all of your JavaScript with this it might do what you'd like.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#Map area").click(function(){
        $('.boxes').hide();
        $('#' + this.id + 'D').animate({
            width: "toggle"
        });
    });
});
```

If you need to animate the boxes closing, you should take a look at the jQuery animate callback documentation.

http://api.jquery.com/animate/